# How to use jQuery UI Accordion with Loop

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, loops, accordion

This is jquery accordion code for effect:

```
 $(function() {
            $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
            header: "h3"
            });
       });
```

This is the output of database (mysql) which is loop (uncertain loop):

```
 while($showE = mysqli_fetch_array($show))
            {

            echo $showE['un_name'];  /* this should be accordion head */
            echo $showE['un_name_dec']; /* this should be accordion description */
            }
```

So my question is, how to show them in accordion effect, everything is working( i can fetch records from database), but accordion effect is not forming, (accordion effect is not working) and how to show them with loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you have two files: index.html and load_entries.php

index.html:

```
<html>
   <head>
       <!-- Make the imports of your stylesheets and scripts here -->
       <script type="text/javascript">
           $(function() {
              $("#accordion").accordion({header: "h3"});
           });
           function load_entries() {
              $.ajax({
                  url: "load_entries.php",
                  complete: function(data) {
                      $("#accordion").html(data.responseText);
                  }
              });
           }
       </script>
   </head>
   <body>
       <button onclick="load_entries();">Load</button> <!-- Button to load the entries -->
       <div id="accordion">

       </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

load_entries.php:

```
<?php
   //connect to your database here
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM entries"; //replace entries by your own table name
   $result = mysqli_query($sql);
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo '<h3>'.$row['un_name'].'</h3>';
      echo '<div>'.$row['un_name_dec'].'</div>';
   }
?>
```

Comment: now the code should also add the javascript code which creates the accordion

Comment: and how to fetch them using jquery ajax ($.ajax Or $.post Or load() )

Answer (score 2):

**jquery Script**

```
$.post('server.php', function(data) {

$("#accordion").html(data);

$("#accordion").accordion();

});
```

**Server.php**

```
$html='';
while($showE = mysqli_fetch_array($show)) {
$html.= '<h3>'.$showE['un_name'].'</h3>';
$html.= '<div>'.$showE['un_name_dec'].'</div>';
}
echo $html;
```

**HTML MARKUP**

```
<div id='accordion'></div>
```

Comment: i know that, but i dont know how to show them in jquery accordion using (append or something)